# Previous financial year - parameter expression for SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I currently use:

> =IIF(Today() >= DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1),DateSerial(Year(Today()), 4, 1), DateSerial(Year(Today()) - 1, 4, 1))

and

> =DATESERIAL(Year(Now()) + (IIF(format(now(),"MMdd") > "0331",1,0))  ,3,31)

to get me the current financial year (UK) dates, eg 1/4/2020 - 31/3/2021

Please can you advise how I'd adapt these to bring through the previous financial year, e.g:

1/4/2019 - 31/3/2020  ?

Many thanks

Comment: Just use the DateAdd() function. `=DATEADD(datepart.Year, -1, YourCurrentFYExpressionHere)`

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to get back. I tried that but got an error message: 'overload resolution failed because no accessible datepart accepts this number of arguments'. I had closed the final bracket.

Comment: I didn't show this but you would have to put your expression inside brackets (excluding the = sign) . Although you could just change all the parts of your existing code that calculate the year to subtract 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting my brain into gear I worked this out:

**From date:**

> =DATESERIAL(cstr(Year(today())-1) - (IIF(format(now(),"MMdd") > "0331",0,1)) ,4,1)

**To date:**

> =DATESERIAL(cstr(Year(Now())-1) + (IIF(format(now(),"MMdd") > "0331",1,0)) ,3,31)